# WiX skip dialog with conditions

Tags: dialog, wix

I have a custom dialog that is showen when `InstallPEDatabase` feature is selected.
Here is that part of the sequence where `MyEditConfig` is my custom dialog:

```
  <Publish Dialog="MyCustomizeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="MyEditConfigDlg"><![CDATA[(&CreatePEDatabase=3)]]></Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="MyCustomizeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg"><![CDATA[NOT(&CreatePEDatabase=3)]]></Publish>

  <Publish Dialog="MyEditConfigDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="MyEditConfigDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MyCustomizeDlg">1</Publish>

  <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MyCustomizeDlg" Order="1">NOT CreatePEDatabase = 3 AND NOT Installed OR WixUI_InstallMode = "Change"</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MyEditConfigDlg" Order="2">CreatePEDatabase = 3 AND NOT Installed OR WixUI_InstallMode = "Change"</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Order="3">Installed AND NOT PATCH</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="WelcomeDlg" Order="4">Installed AND PATCH</Publish>
```

Like this it works for selecting the feature then the `MyEditConfigDlg` is presented and when feature is not selected then it is not presented. The problem is that when i click next from my custom dialog and go to `VerifyReadyDlg` and click back from there it takes me back to the `MyCustomizeDlg` instead of `MyEditConfigDlg.` I know there is something wrong with the conditions, but i just cant figure out what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax of the "feature" CreatePEDatabase is being specified as a "property" (variable without a prefix). You need to prefix features with an ampersand. As it is now, the test is asking "NOT(Is the Property CreatePEDatabase =3)" which will be true because that property doesn't exist and is not equal to anything.
If you change the syntax to a feature, then it will be evaluted correctly.

Here's a great summary of the syntax used by the MSI engine (which reads the WiX resulting MSI file):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368012(VS.85).aspx

Also, you can omit the "Order" values, as those are only used in special cases of multiple dialogs for the same conditions. Your tests will make each situation unique.